# HP DL380 using HP NC522SFP NIC shows supported link modes: not reported

Tags: network-adapter

When using ethtool on this NIC, the supported link modes show "not reported".  Any idea why this is the case?

Settings for eth0:

```
Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
Supported link modes:   Not reported 
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: No
Advertised link modes:  Not reported
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: 10000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: FIBRE
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: external
Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00002000 (8192)
               hw
Link detected: yes
```